# 1000hz Bootstrap validator not submit when validate triggered - Laravel

Tags: jquery, forms, laravel-5, form-submit, bootstrapvalidator

Bootstrap validator form not submit after all validate error is corrected, but if no validation is triggered, the form can be submit, here is my form:

```
{!! Form::open(["method" => "POST", "action" => "user\UserWalletController@transfer", "id" => "transferModal", "class" => "modal fade", "aria-labelledby" => "transferModal", "aria-hidden" => "true"]) !!}
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h5 class="modal-title colorOrange1">Transfer</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
                {!! Form::checkbox("agreeTermsOfUse", null, null, ["id" => "termsOfUse", "data-error" => "You must agree Terms of Use", "required"]) !!}
                <label for="termsOfUse"> I agree with Terms Of Use </label>
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" id="submitTransferDetails" class="btn bgTeal1" name="operationBtn" value="transferFund">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

here is my form validate function is JS:

```
$('#transferModal').validator();
```

i updated my code like this, it will submit the form, but it will take 1000 of console log then only come out an error and submit, why it will like this??

```
$('#transferModal').validator().on('submit', function (e) {
  if ($("input[name='transferPasswordStatus']").val() == "true") {
    if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
      // handle the invalid form...
    } else {
      console.log("eooer");
      $(this).submit();
    }
  }
  else if ($("input[name='transferPasswordStatus']").val() == "false") {
    alert("Password mismatch");
  }
});
```

here is the printscreen:

[image]

i have tested several time and the submit button name is not "submit" also, but it just not submit at all.

What is the problem and how can i solve it??

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to enable validation otherwise, without js?

Like that:

```
<form role="form" data-toggle="validator">
  ...
</form>
```

Comment: Yes, i have tried that option before, the result is the same, i have updated my question, console log return some error on submitting.

Comment: Hm, don't even know.. here is the fiddle and everything works there
https://jsfiddle.net/d1e8ghxj/3/